# How do I edit the format of things published to the front page?

Tags: views, media, nodes

How do I change the way info is published to the front page?

For example, it gives me a title, 1 paragraph of body, date, tags and a read more button.  I need to set it so that it also gives me a particular image field from a custom content type on top of the body content.

Where do I make this correction?  I don't see it anywhere in views and I don't want to redesign my front-page around a different block / new view.

Comment: Need more information. What is the relationship between the image ant the node? Is it attached to or referenced from the page, or is it simply a common image displayed for that content type?

Comment: After some research I'm finding that I need to change the view mode.  ie: where it says content, teaser, i need to create another one that is basically teaser + image field.  

After some research I've discovered that this is possible with Display Suite.. but that feels like overkill.  It seems like there should be an easier/lighter way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It also possible with Views, if you set the Style (listed in the Basic Settings section) to Fields. You can then choose whatever Fields you like to be displayed.

Like you already mention yourself, it is possible with Display Suite. If you choose to work with Display Suite, you can select a Display Suite build mode in the Style option of a View.

Comment: I've decided to go with this views approach.  

For anyone else looking at it, keep in mind though you have to remove the original content feed on the homepage and you will no longer be able to "publish to homepage"

Thanks for posting.